# Solr - limit the number of results from a certain type

Tags: solr

I wonder if I can limit the number of results from a certain type.

For example, I make a search for 40 results, I want to get maximum 4 docs marked as 'promoted'. Assume that I have a boolean field, which indicates if the document should be promoted or not (`promoted: true\false`).

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be by using the [DiversifiedTopDocsCollector](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6066), but it has not been exposed at Solr level yet.

The other alternative is to use [grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) or [collapsing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results) and try to achieve what you need with the params.